# How is it possible to "duck type" an object when the Class has encapsulated properties?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if it is a good practice to use accessors in TS, and is I was testing cases I noticed that doing so, makes you lose the "feature" of "duck-typing".
Is it by design to prevent developers for unwanted mistyping 
or am I missing something?

```js
    class BlogPost {
        constructor(private _title: string, private _summary: string,
                    private _hoverTitle?: string) { 
        }
        public get title(): string {
            return this._title;
        }
        public set title(value: string) {
            this._title = value;
        }

        public get summary(): string {
            return this._summary;
        }
        public set summary(value: string) {
            this._summary = value;
        }

        public get hoverTitle(): string {
            return this._hoverTitle;
        }
        public set hoverTitle(value: string) {
            this._hoverTitle = value;
        }
    }

    let blogPostItem: BlogPost;

    blogPostItem = {
        hoverTitle = '',
        summary = '',
        title = ''
    }
```

This should be a valid assignment but it shows me the following error:

*Property 'hoverTitle' is missing in type '{ title: string; _title: string; summary: string; _summary: any; }' but required in type 'BlogPost'.*

When I try to add these properties , as they are private it shows this error:

*Type '{ _hoverTitle: any; _summary: any; _title: any; hoverTitle: any; summary: any; title: any; }' is not assignable to type 'BlogPost'.
  Property '_title' is private in type 'BlogPost' but not in type '{ _hoverTitle: any; _summary: any; _title: any; hoverTitle: any; summary: any; title: any; }'.*

**Is this intended or I'm missing something?**

[Here is a live preview of the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20BlogPost%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20_title%3A%20string%2C%20private%20_summary%3A%20string%2C%20private%20_hoverTitle%3F%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20title()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._title%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20title(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._title%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20summary()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._summary%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20summary(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._summary%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20hoverTitle()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._hoverTitle%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20hoverTitle(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._hoverTitle%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20blogPostItem%3A%20BlogPost%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AblogPostItem%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20summary%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hoverTitle%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_hoverTitle%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_summary%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_title%3A%20''%0D%0A%7D)

---

I think this is a good way to handle the problem! [preview](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20BlogPost%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20summary%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hoverTitle%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BlogPostImpl%20implements%20BlogPost%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20_title%3A%20string%2C%20private%20_summary%3A%20string%2C%20private%20_hoverTitle%3F%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20title()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._title%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20title(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fmaybe%20some%20functionality%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._title%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20summary()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._summary%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20summary(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fmaybe%20some%20functionality%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._summary%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20hoverTitle()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._hoverTitle%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20hoverTitle(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fmaybe%20some%20functionality%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._hoverTitle%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20blogPostItem%3A%20BlogPost%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AblogPostItem%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20summary%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hoverTitle%3A%20''%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AblogPostItem%20%3D%20new%20BlogPostImpl('title'%2C%20'desc')%3B)

Just have the class implement an interface and then use interface for "duck typing"... this ways doesn't matter if the class has encapsulated private fields because you are typing as the interface.

This came from [@Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Privates make the class behave nominally, it not possible to alias a class with private fields. We can on the other hand remove them by using `Pick` to get only the public properties:

```
let blogPostItem: Pick<BlogPost, keyof BlogPost>;

blogPostItem = {
    hoverTitle: '',
    summary: '',
    title: ''
}
```

You can also use a type assertion to ignore the errors.

Comment: I would say that private properties make the *instance type* behave nominally; they don't behave nominally themselves, since you can't even name them in a valid way outside of the class.

Comment: Ok, typing `blogPostItem` that way works... But the following question is, what if i don't know that the Class Type i want to give to the variable has encapsulated properties? Do i have to type always with Pick or avoid encapsulation in general?

Comment: You shouldn't avoid encapsulation, but in your example encapsulation is weak. The class has private property but they are accessible by get/set.

```

Comment: @jcalz yeah, that's why the compiler can't make structural type checking... But I can't believe that encapsulation comes in conflict with structural typing. I just try to find out how and if it is possible to have encapsulated fields and "duck typing" that class without relying on knowing the way the class was built.

Comment: @meniosmpouras If it has private fields, you will get an error and you can then change to `Pick`. This is the problem with compile-time only private fields. They are only enforced by the compiler and to make sure that nobody is messing around with private state all consumers are to a degree aware of the private fields (ex. extended classes can't have fields with the same name, you can't augment the class with a fields with the same name). When true runtime private fields come along they will probably not matter to type compatibility as they are completely invisible outside the class

Comment: @jcalz 10x it was indeed a bad choice of words.

Comment: @meniosmpouras I would also suggest that generally this is not a good idea, sure ts allows object literals to satisfy a class type, but `instanceof` for example wil lnot behave as expected as the object literal is not truly an instance of the class. I would not declare a class like you do in the exmple, I would just use an interface with the fields, no need for verbose getter/setter in JS/TS, it is just not a common pattern unless you actually have logic in those getter/setters

Comment: @aquz The reason to encapsulate properties is to prevent direct access, isn't it?I access properties with `getters/setters`, if i have a reason not to, I could delete `setters`... I work mostly on Java and my question was if I have to avoid encapsulation in __TypeScript__; because I don't see TS code use get/set often.

Comment: You can use `readonly` of the fields if you don't want to allow writes to a field (although it is not a very strong modifier). The TS/JS world does not use this pattern at all to my knowledge.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for the explanation, i get it now... I keep forgetting that it is a developing time warning from TS compiler for possible mistakes. I thought that this could lead to a run-time error. So, after all  get/set are not necessary in TS...  I will also follow your advice for coding on interfaces, that was just an example though...

Comment: @aquz the issue is not related to whether the encapsulation is weak or not. It is because type of class in TS behaves nominally.

Comment: "they are completely invisible outside the class" this still matters to type compatibility unless they are also invisible to other instances of the same class.  Otherwise `class Oops { #prop = "hey"; trouble(other: Oops){other.#prop.charAt(0);} }` will still require that `Oops` be essentially nominal to prevent someone from calling `(new Oops()).trouble(x)` on some `x` that only conforms to the public interface of `Oops`.

Answer (score 2):

To amend @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir answer,

> Privates make the class behave nominally.

Notice he says "behave nominally", but not "nominal".

the type of Class in TypeScript includes private fields and compare them structurally. It is a design choice made by the TS team to avoid accidental access or overriding the private fields.

It does create a lot of confusion and pain points, and one of the main driving force for myself to do class-less programming in TS.

The `Pick<>` is a nice trick to get around this "limitation".